# RAZR cuts off call ring after half a second

Tags: notifications, calls, ringtone

My Droid RAZR (original model, 18 mos. old), seems to have an issue where when a call comes in it will start to play the ring tone but then the sound shuts off after half a second. The call is still there, but unless I feel the single vibration in my pocket (I have it set to vibrate *and* ring), I don't know to answer it.

This totally blows.

Is there any way I can force this phone to ring a certain number of times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just called Verizon Customer Care. They had me dial *900 and that fixed the issue. This cancels any possible call forwarding. Works like a champ now.